# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have an application where I create excel files with `apache POI 3.17`
I am having this error message from `apache POI` logs when I run the application in `Tomcat`. What does this mean and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What version of Apache Tomcat are you using? What other XML parsers are on your classpath?

Comment: This is likely caused by having an ancient XML parser on your classpath - eg https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781657/ - can you upgrade to xerces 2.12.0?

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! You are right, the problem was an XML parser (xalan) in my case, Tho, doesn't apache poi have its own xml parser?

Comment: Apache POI like most Java projects uses https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jaxp/index.html - basically, it is up to the user to ensure they have their JVM set up correctly

Comment: see also: http://developerblogging.blogspot.com/2013/04/javalangabstractmethoderror.html

Comment: I resolved the same error exluding the xerces-impl library.

Answer (score 6):

I ended up add this to the eclipse.ini file:
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

Comment: All seems to be working now after reading this:http://developerblogging.blogspot.com/2013/04/javalangabstractmethoderror.html. If you will scroll down to the bottom.  So I added the above line to my eclipse.ini file.  Restarted and was finally able to run tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this abstract Method error due to Xerces Jar, it needed to be upgraded.
i Excluded it from the dependency where it was a transitive dependency and added a latest version jar as a new dependency and it worked.