# NoSuchMethodError: setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a very similar error to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722815/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-javax-xml-parsers-documentbuilderfactory-setfeatu) other question, but the fix they found doesn't fix mine. When trying to generate an XSSFWorkbook (`workbook.write(fileOut);`) I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
```

Maybe it is an XML parser error, but I use neither xalan nor xerces. It's a big company project with lots of dependencies I don't always have control over. I use stax 1.0.1, saxon 9, xml-resolver 1.2 (for poi 3.17). I'm not sure which ones are relevant to this specific issue however.

What does this mean and how do I fix this?

EDIT: Updated to version 3.17, the problem is the same.

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI with known security issues? What happens when you upgrade to something supported?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Java 1.6

Comment: @Gagravarr I didn't think it mattered as it's used only for one small thing that is fully internal to the company. But that's just my original thought, probably not a good reason. I also picked an old one because I knew this one would work with 1.6. Are all versions compatible with older versions of Java?

Comment: Java 1.6 has been out of support (including security support) for ages too! You really better hope your perimeter security, IDS, incident management etc is up to scratch...

Comment: @Gagravarr Believe me, it's not my choice to use 1.6, but I can't do anything about it. Do you think it would work better with a more recent version of Apache POI?

Comment: You can't move to Apache POI 4.x, but you can move to the latest 3.x release of 3.17 for [lots and lots of bug fixes](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html)

Comment: @Gagravarr I moved to 3.17 and I still have this error. What should I do?

Comment: You might need to manually backport the fix from 4.0, you might be safe to just drop in the latest helper class from 4.0

Comment: @Gagravarr Do you have any guarantee that it will fix it? It's not something I can do easily and I need to be sure. I have to formulate a request for someone else to add the jar on the repo and stuff.